# Element position changes on window resize in webkit browsers, despite absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, webkit, position, css-position

I have an element sitting on top of an image on a site. The image loads in the window in it's correct position in all browsers, and relocates to where it belongs in all browsers except webkit (Safari and Chrome specifically). In webkit browsers, the second you try to resize the window, it relocates the element below the image and sets its margins relative to the image.

Here's my html:

```
<body>

<div class="header-image">
  <img id="headerimg" src="images/header.jpg" alt="" />
  <img id="link-header" src="images/link-header.png" alt="" />
</div>

</body>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
body { max-width:1236px; margin:0 auto; position:relative; }
.header-image { width:100%; height:auto; max-width:1236px; margin:0 auto; position:relative; }
#headerimg { width:100%; max-width:1236px; height:auto; }
#link-header { position:absolute; right:0; margin-right:10%; margin-top:275px; }
```

Like I said, every other browser does the resize just fine. It's only webkit that I'm experiencing this issue. Any ideas at all?

Comment: What element does it "relocate" ?

Comment: so much easier if you make a JSFiddle or CodePen :)

Comment: It's the #link-header element that relocates. I'd like to do a jsfiddle, but this is for work and I'm unable to post any images due to compliance issues. Sorry about that. Any ideas though?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely has nothing to do with images as I am not using any and have experienced the same strange sizing, positioning and centering behavior on Chome above 1159px and also on apple's safari above 1209px but on apple the behavior is slightly different. The sizes between 1235px and 1250px are differently weird. I realize this is not a great diagnostic post, but it's as good as I've got at the moment. I'll post more if/when I discover more. This was tested on a winXP machine after a resize. I've been scratching my head for hours so you're definitely not alone.

In your case setting the size below 1200px if you can, should solve it. Sorry I don't have more help.